What is the distribution of incidence rate and its standard error
this problem has stayed with me for a long time. I googled, and tried chatbots but no luck.
The incidence rate here is in the form of xxx cases / yyy person-time. What I am tyring to figure out is its distribution and the standard error of it.
I appreciate your help.
Any ideas?
